# change directory on boot and run script on boot?

Tags: debian, web-server, script

I have recently been experimenting and exposing myself to Linux thanks to the Raspberry Pi, but after a lot of researching, I found a way to sync a folder to all nodes on my local web server. I am learning about clustered environments and how clusters generally work. I had the Pi's so I thought why not feast. :D

Question is however, I have the script onchange.sh to execute it properly so that it syncs to all the other local remote hosts, I need to be in the directory. I am using pyplate as my CMS so directory is /usr/share/pyplate.

How does one achieve this so that when I boot up the Pi's, it automatically changes directory to /usr/pyplate and then runs the script.

Thanks and sorry about the lengthy post, I thought explanation was necessary.

Comment: This would fit better on [unix.se], as this issue is more of a generic Linux issue than a Raspberry Pi-specific one.

Answer (score 2):

There are probably dozens of ways.

I use crontab (man crontab) for this sort of job, others prefer to add an entry in /etc/rc.local just before the final line (exit 0).

crontab is used to schedule jobs.  One option is to schedule a job on reboot.

If your script needs to be run as root add it to /etc/rc.local or to the root crontab.

sudo crontab -e

If your script doesn't need to be run as root add it your personal crontab.

crontab -e

The crontab entry should be something like

@reboot       (sleep 10; cd  /usr/share/pyplate; ./onchange.sh)

The sleep may not be needed.  It may need to be increased to allow all external resources to be accessible.

This is one method, there are others.

---

EDITED TO ADD

To manually run the command you can do something like the following.

Create a file in /usr/local/bin called mysync with the following content

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /usr/share/pyplate
nohup ./onchange.sh &
```

Then just type mysync to run the script.  The nohup will allow the script to run to completion even if you terminate its parent session.

Comment: Well ultimately the problem is that this there is a script called onchange.sh that I like using since I have a home brewed web server cluster with 6 nodes with a load balancer (created it too). I want to run this script but if I run it via ssh then when I exit the ssh session, it kills the current process too... Also, in order to run this script, I have to be in /usr/share/pyplate because that's what will be syncing. Any suggestions? :o

Comment: Is that a new question? I thought I mentioned a couple of ways of doing it at boot.  I'll add a method of doing the same post boot.

Comment: No I was redefining the original. I tried crontab method, I rebooted the server and then created a test file. I trashed pyplate idea and went with something simple. Here is my crontab. The test file created in /usr/share/nginx/www did not sync to the second node. http://prntscr.com/5vjju2

Comment: That's another question update.  I have no idea what all those parameters to onchange.sh do.